# RegEx :- Need to write a regex which should not allow digits

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression which should not allow any digits. it should allow any other characters except digits. I tried expression like :- ~[0-9]+

but it restricts everything. could you pls help me?

Comment: Could you add a tag for the language you need this regex for?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what flavor of regex you need, but in the general, one of the following should work:

```
^[^0-9]*$
^[^\d]*$
^\D*$
^[[:^digit:]]*$
^\P{IsDigit}*$
```

The last two forms will work with Unicode digits.

The atom `[^0-9]` matches anything *but* a digit; to make sure that in the whole string there are no digits, I added the markers of string start (`^`) and end (`$`).

If you want to match any part of a string that contains at least one character that is not a digit, replace the `^...*$` part of the regex by `...+`:

```
[^0-9]+
\D+
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[^0-9]+`. Note that this will only prevent ASCII digits from appearing, not unicode ones.